# objective-c add / combine a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have these two strings here:

```
Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", LongitudeDouble];
Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", LatitudeDouble];
```

What I am trying to do now is add the words Longitude: and Latitude: how do I add these works to the string I have created which are doubles.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the desired text to the format string:

```
Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %.10f", LongitudeDouble];
```

BTW - standard naming conventions dictate that variable and method names should start with lowercase letters. Class names begin with uppercase letters.